# Tag wiki privilege

Tags: support, editing, privileges, tag-wiki

I was informed that I have gained the [tag wiki edit privilege](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

My assumption was that it works similar to the question and answer edit privilege, i.e. it does not require peer review any more and I could just edit the tag wiki with changes becoming immediately effective.

However, when I edited the [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/open-source/info) tag wiki, it still says that peer review is needed:

[image: Tag wiki edit notification]

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Thomas.  I just approved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.

The privilege you mention is the privilege of reviewing tag wiki edits proposed by others.  These proposals appear in the *Suggested Edits* review queue alongside suggested edits of posts.

Any edit that you propose must still be reviewed.

In order to edit a tag wiki without your edit being reviewed by others, the privilege is [*Trusted User*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).  This is achieved at a reputation level of 20,000.

Comment: Woah, 20000 on this site, that's ~9 years from now if I can keep my rep-rate.